# Thymeleaf: th:insert doesn`t work while th:replace works well

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I`m using Spring Boot + Thymeleaf. This is my *pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Project Structure (the relevant part):

```
-src
   -main
      -resources
         -templates
            -fragments
               navbar.html
            home.html
```

In the *navbar.html* I have the following fragment:

```
<nav th:fragment="navbar">...</nav>
```

In the *home.html* I`m using the fragment above:

1. `<div th:insert="fragments/navbar :: navbar"></div>`
2. `<div th:replace="fragments/navbar :: navbar"></div>`

**The question is: why the first variant (with th:insert) doesn`t work while the second variant (with th:replace) works fine?**

**P. S.** I have read the docs and expected the following:

```
<!-- with th:insert -->
<div>
    <nav>...</nav>
</div>

<!-- with th:replace -->
<nav>...</nav>
```